# Httaccess RewriteRule custom link 404 but can access

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am using `RewriteRule` for custom link, 404 on console but link can be accessed. screen capture below:

[image: Screenshot of "/about" page with 404 response]

All custom link have same problem but can be accessed.

Htaccess code below :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.simenteknindo.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://simenteknindo.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^career$ career.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^404$ 404.php [L,NC]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</IfModule>
```

I try add `[L,NC]` on `htaccess` and check all resource on website but nothing help for solving, I hope someone help this problem.

Comment: Your problem does not appear to have anything to do with `.htaccess`. Requesting `/about.php` and `/career.php` directly also returns a 404 (although `/home` returns a 404 when `/index.php` returns returns a 200 OK)?! This looks more like an issue with your PHP code?